# Zend Form - How to set values on sub form elements?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

```
array 
'subQuantity' => 
array
  'quantity_6' => string '23' (length=2)
  'quantity_16' => string '23' (length=2)
  'quantity_18' => string '23' (length=2)
'update' => string 'Update' (length=6)
```

Good day! I just created a subform from my existing zend form and procures this data when form submits. Based on posted data (the quantity_ elements), I would like to set the values to subform elements. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.
cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure whether you want to set values of individual subform elements or all of them at once. Nevertheless you can use populate method. For example:

```
 $yourForm->populate(array(
    'subQuantity' => array(
        'quantity_6' => 'some value 1',
        'quantity_16' => 'some value 2',
        'quantity_18' => 'some value 3',
    )
));
```

EDIT:

Here are few ways of setting individual fields:

```
$yourForm->populate(array(
        'subQuantity' => array(     
            'quantity_16' => 'some value',
        )
 ));

 // OR

 $yourForm->getSubForm('subQuantity')->getElement('quantity_16')->setValue('some value');

 // this also should work (not sure if it works with underscore in 'quantity_16' though)

 $yourForm->subQuantity->quantity_16->setValue('some value');
```

Comment: hi Marcin, Good day! Thanks for your prompt reply. I just wanted to set values as per individual form elements. The code you posted might be a good help for some other time. Can you show me how to do it appropriately, it would be a big help. Thanks and more power.

Comment: @Zend_Newbie_Dev. I added edited my answer to include setting individual values.

Comment: @Zend_Newbie_Dev: But that exact same question was asked already by you yesterday, and has already been answered yesterday (also by Marcin BTW). Why ask it again?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $formSuper = new ContractLink_Form_ContractAllotmentSuper();
    foreach($allotments as $key => $allotment)
    {
        $form = new ContractLink_Form_ContractAllotment();
        $form->populate($allotment);
        $formSuper->addSubForm($form, 'contractAllotmentForm' . $key);
    }
```