# Zend 1.12: Zend_Form_Element_Text default value

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to create the subform array of text inputs but I am  failing to set the default value.

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $this->products[$product['product_id']] = $product;
    $product['amount']=0;
    $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text(array(
        'name' => 'products[' . $product['product_id'] . ']',
            'id' => $product['product_id'],
            'label' => $product['name'],
            'class' => 'product-amount',
            'filters' => array('StringTrim'),
            'decorators' => array('Label', 'ViewHelper'),
            'validators' => array('Digits')
            ));
    $element->setValue("0");
}
```

Comment: I copy-pasted this into my project and it's working perfectly for me. Could you please extend the idea of "failing to set the default value"?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546125/zend-form-how-to-set-values-on-sub-form-elements

Comment: The above code seams actually works. The problem was in the way the form was called (the form required to submit the form, decide what extra field to add, sand back).  The form after adding the fields was marked as invalid and the default values were then missing. Simply skipping the validation in that case and rendering the form solved the problem.

Comment: I think you can post that as an answer. Even if it is an answer to your question. At least people will know that it has been solved already. cheers!